# Maven Shade Plugin - NoClassDefFound

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javax.imageio

I am trying to create a jar to send to a colleague for testing purposes. My program works fine on the Eclipse IDE. However, when I try to use mvn install and mvn package to compile it into a jar, when I try to run the jar, I get the following error: 
[NoClassDefFound][1] (click on the link to see the screenshot).

Here is my POM file:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.geotools.tutorial.tutorialCerto</groupId>
<artifactId>tutorialCerto</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>tutorial</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>15.1</geotools.version>
    <geotools.version>17-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geotiff</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-image</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-wms</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>boundless</id>
        <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <source>1.8</source>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>shade</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                      <transformers>
                          <!-- This bit sets the main class for the executable jar as you otherwise -->
                          <!-- would with the assembly plugin                                       -->
                          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                              <manifestEntries>
                                  <Main-Class>org.geotools.tutorial.tutorialCerto.ImageLab</Main-Class>
                              </manifestEntries>
                          </transformer>
                          <!-- This bit merges the various GeoTools META-INF/services files         -->
                          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                      </transformers>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I would be really grateful if someone could help me to figure out what's happening.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 2**

I added the following code just for testing purposes on my program:

package com.br.iacit.tutorialdoJar;

```
public class App {
public static void main( String[] args )
{      System.out.println(com.sun.media.imageioimpl.common.PackageUtil.getVendor());
}
```

}

On eclipse ide it shows Sun Microsystems, Inc. however in my jar file it prints null. Maybe it has something to do with it?

Comment: you are defining two properties with the same name

Comment: do you mean     <geotools.version>15.1</geotools.version>
    <geotools.version>17-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version> ? If so, it's the API default :)

Comment: yes, try to use only one of them (which is what Maven will do).

Comment: alright, changed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the following attributes to my pom file:

```
<manifestEntries>
    <Main-Class>com.br.iacit.tutorialdoJar.ImageLab</Main-Class>
    <Specification-Title>Java Advanced Imaging Image I/O Tools</Specification-Title>
    <Specification-Version>1.1</Specification-Version>
    <Specification-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Specification-Vendor>
    <Implementation-Title>com.sun.media.imageio</Implementation-Title>
    <Implementation-Version>1.1</Implementation-Version>
    <Implementation-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Implementation-Vendor>
</manifestEntries>
```

Here is my final POM file:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.br.iacit</groupId>
<artifactId>tutorialdoJar</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>tutorialdoJar</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>17-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geotiff</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-image</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-wms</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-imageio-ext-gdal</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>boundless</id>
        <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <source>1.8</source>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <!-- This bit sets the main class for the executable jar as you otherwise -->
                            <!-- would with the assembly plugin -->
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>com.br.iacit.tutorialdoJar.ImageLab</Main-Class>
                                    <Specification-Title>Java Advanced Imaging Image I/O Tools</Specification-Title>
                                    <Specification-Version>1.1</Specification-Version>
                                    <Specification-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Specification-Vendor>
                                    <Implementation-Title>com.sun.media.imageio</Implementation-Title>
                                    <Implementation-Version>1.1</Implementation-Version>
                                    <Implementation-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Implementation-Vendor>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                            <!-- This bit merges the various GeoTools META-INF/services files -->
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Which Manifest? One you created in your project I suppose ?

Comment: check the tag <manifestEntries></manifestEntries>. I added some attributes. Before, I had only the <Main-Class></Main-Class> specification.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the dependencies in your classpath, to correct this you might use the maven dependency plugin:

```
     <build>
         <plugins>
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>
```

Then you would need also to add the classpath to your manifest, for shade I think you need to add in `<ManifestEntries>` the following:

```
 <Class-Path>${project.build.directory}/lib</Class-Path>
```

**Edit: Fair enough** if you don't need the shade plugin, what I can suggest to you is the pom below, which uses a simpler plugin to compile the depedencies, the [maven dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test.whatever</groupId>
    <artifactId>shade-tester</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>shade-tester</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>15.1</geotools.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-geotiff</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-image</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-wms</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>boundless</id>
            <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
<!--                Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.test.whatever.shade_tester.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*log4j*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> -->
            <!-- <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> -->
            <!-- <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId> -->
            <!-- <version>3.0.0</version> -->
            <!-- <executions> -->
            <!-- <execution> -->
            <!-- <phase>package</phase> -->
            <!-- <goals> -->
            <!-- <goal>shade</goal> -->
            <!-- </goals> -->
            <!-- <configuration> -->
            <!-- <transformers> -->
            <!-- This bit sets the main class for the executable jar as you otherwise -->
            <!-- would with the assembly plugin -->
            <!-- <transformer -->
            <!-- implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer"> -->
            <!-- <manifestEntries> -->
            <!-- <Main-Class>org.test.whatever.shade_tester.App</Main-Class> -->
            <!-- <Class-Path>lib/</Class-Path> -->
            <!-- </manifestEntries> -->
            <!-- </transformer> -->
            <!-- This bit merges the various GeoTools META-INF/services files -->
            <!-- <transformer -->
            <!-- implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" 
                /> -->
            <!-- </transformers> -->
            <!-- </configuration> -->
            <!-- </execution> -->
            <!-- </executions> -->
            <!-- </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. now it's giving me the error that it could not find the main class, however, it is on my package. I have updated my answer!

Comment: Very strange, this configuration works well in my case... Perhaps you could try to update your maven shade version to 3.0.0.  When you run mvn do you clean first? (i.e. mvn clean package or mvn clean install)

Comment: it's already 3.0.0 on my pom file. :(  I run mvn clean package and after that mvn package.

Comment: My bad I am slightly tired...  One other thing, if you unzip your jar, could you tell me what's in the MANIFEST.MF file, and if you have all your dependencies in the lib folder?

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Raquel
Class-Path: C:\Users\Raquel\workspace\tutorialCerto\target/lib
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_60
Main-Class: org.geotools.tutorial.tutorialCerto.ImageLab  and yes, my dependencies are there on the target/lib.

Comment: Ok, very strange ... And is it normal than in your first screenshot you execute the jar original-ddd.jar, and in the second one you use ddd-shaded.jar?

Comment: I have currently three jars on the target directory, original-tutorialCerto-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, tutorialCerto-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, tutorialCerto-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded. I have run all them multiple times to see if there was a different result, but they all produce the same output

Comment: Do you absolutely need the shade plugin by the way? Otherwise I suggest to use the maven dependency plugin, see my edited post

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and your help, Asettouf. I solved my problem adding some manifest entries and then my old pom file worked. That's really strange, though.

Answer (score 0):

i faced same issue. but now its working fine for me.
try below steps.

first you need to delete this ' .m2 ' file from given location

Windows: C:\Users\.m2

then - update your maven project.
then  - clean install and everything seems to be fine